# Find $\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{\arctan (2x)}{3x}}$ without using '0/0=1'

Tags: calculus, limits

Find limit as 
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\arctan (2x)}{3x}
$$
without using $\frac{0}{0} = 1$.

I wanted to use 
$$
\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{0}{0} = \frac{2}{3} \cdot 1,
$$ 
but our teacher considers $\frac{0}{0}$ a "dangerous case" and we are not allowed to use this method.

We have not studied integrals yet, so I cannot use integral formulas. We have only studied a bit of derivative taking...

I tried many substitutions, but failed :( Any suggestion?

Comment: @user283294 What do you mean "without 0/0 = 1" ? What are the rules of calculating this limit?

Comment: Did you do L'Hospital rules yet?

Comment: The argument that "$0/0 = 1$" is not only a dangerous method, it is utterly and completely FALSE. It is never allowed and your teacher should say so clearly.

Comment: @user283294 I agree with 5xum - you should use L'Hospital's Rule as it is a $0/0$ case.

Answer (score 11):

Let $u=\arctan(2x)$ Then as $ x \rightarrow 0$ we have $u \rightarrow 0$ So $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\arctan(2x)}{3x}=\lim_{u \rightarrow 0} \frac{u}{3 \frac{tan(u)}{2}}=\frac{2}{3}\lim_{u \rightarrow 0 } \cos(x) \cdot \frac{u}{\sin(u)}=\frac{2}{3} \lim_{u \rightarrow 0} \frac{u}{\sin(u)} \cdot \lim_{u \rightarrow 0} \cos(u) $

Comment: This is the best approach, in my view. Exactly how I did it. +1 for you.

Answer (score 5):

This is really just the derivative of the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{3} \arctan 2x$ at $x = 0$, written down using the definition. Since you know that $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{3} \arctan 2x = \frac{1}{3} \frac{2}{1 + (2x) ^2}$ (check this!), you obtain the result $\frac{2}{3}$ by substituting $x = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

You may use L'Hospital's rule:
$$
\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{\arctan (2x)}{3x}}=\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{\frac{2}{1+4x^2}}{3}}=\frac23.
$$

Answer (score 2):

*With equivalents:*

We know $\arctan u\sim_0u$, hence 
$$\frac{\arctan 2x}{3x}\sim_0\frac{2x}{3x}=\frac23.$$